# Are type 2 hypersensitivities autoimmune diseases?

Tags: immune-system, allergy, autoimmune-disease

I'm learning about hypersensitivities and it seems to me that all type 2 hypersensitivities are autoimmune diseases; also all examples of type 2 hypersensitivity I've heard so far are also classified as autoimmune diseases (Grave's disease, Myasthenia gravis etc.). However, couldn't find any explicit mention that all type 2 hypersensitivities are autoimmune diseases. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not all type II Hypersensitivities are autoimmune diseases.
Example: blood transfusion reactions, erythroblastosis fetalis, are also type 2.. but these are not autoimmune.
Type 2 indicates reaction between antigen and antibodies..
Auto-immune means antibody acting against own body cells..
That's why all type 2 is not autoimmune..
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_II_hypersensitivity

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.